# Is there a downside to not using this in JavaScript object constructors?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Compare these two constructors:

**A**

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

**B**

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
  var o = new Object();
  o.name = name;
  o.age = age;
  return o;
}
```

Is there a downside to using B over A (other than brevity)?

Edit: The reason I ask is because I can learn by comparing and contrasting the two, not because I want to use B.

Comment: You waste the object that's already be constructed for you by the runtime system, for one thing.

Comment: yeah, B is not a constructor since it doesn't include prototype memebers in the output instance.

Comment: with B you might as well do `var Person = {name:name,age:age};` as that is basically all you are ending up doing

Comment: B is safer when you forget to use "new " to call a constructor (since it;s not a constructor).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the **upside** to that?

Answer (score 4):

One fairly important difference is that unless you take steps to deal with the issue, the returned object in **B** would not have the "Person" prototype.